# Why don't hyphens display in my app when I include them in my strings.xml file?

Tags: xml, string, android-studio, kotlin

I have defined a string resource in my strings.xml resource file as follows:

```
    <string name="title_counties">--- Counties ---</string>
```

But when I run my app I only see the first three dashes before "Counties" and nothing is displayed after that.

When I edit the string resource to:

```
    <string name="title_counties">--- Counties &#8211;&#8211;&#8211;</string>
```

I still don't see the trailing dashes.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unclear whether you want hyphen-minus or en dash characters, but be aware of the differences between various dashes:

- `-` is a hyphen-minus (`0x2D`) and appears directly on ASCII keyboards.
- ‐ is a hyphen (`&#8208;`)
- – is an en dash (`&#8211;`) and is what your second example has at the end.
- — is an em dash (`&#8212;`)

See [Unicode Characters in the 'Punctuation, Dash' Category](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pd/list.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I increased the width of the text view as the trailing dashes/hyphens were being truncated.